# What is the general time value that I can use in Cassandra, MySQL and Flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter, datetime, cassandra, timestamp

I am using `created_at TIMESTAMP` in my Cassandra schema and have the following code in my NodeJS app:

```
INSERT INTO books (id, user_id, created_at)
VALUES (uuid(), 'userOne', toTimestamp(now()));
```

I like to know, if I am using `created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in my `mysql` app and [DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) in my Flutter application, will these TIMESTAMP values all match together? If not, what can I use for all of them?

In summary, if I use:

`@MySQL` Schema:

```
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

`@Cassandra` Schema and command:

```
//at the Schema
created_at TIMESTAMP
//inside the NodeJS code
INSERT INTO table_name (created_at)
VALUES (toTimestamp(now()));
```

`@Flutter` code:

```
String timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
```

***They all should be same and compatible?***

Comment: What is the TOTIMESTAMP() function? Is it a self written function?

Comment: @GeorgRichter: It's a built-in CQL function: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refCqlFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

The CQL `timestamp` data type is [a 64-bit signed integer that represents the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/types.html#timestamps). On the other hand, the CQL `timeuuid` is a version 1 UUID, i.e. a UUID with a timestamp included.

The CQL `now()` returns the system time in `timeuuid` format and is equivalent to the `currentTimeUuid()` function. When `now()` is nested in `toTimestamp()`, it returns the system time in `timestamp` format.

The CQL `timestamp` type supports BOTH integers and strings.

MySQL converts timestamp values into UTC. When setting CQL `timestamp` columns using MySQL timestamp values as string, it must conform to ISO-8601. The valid formats are:

- `yyyy-mm-dd` (date only)
- `yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss` (date with time)
- `yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss.fff` (with time in millisecond precision)
- `yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss.fff [+/-]NNNN` (with RFC 822 4-digit optional timezone, e.g. `+0000` for GMT or `+1000` for Melbourne)

The Flutter `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch()` returns an integer so it is also compatible with CQL `timestamp` type. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please also have a look at the summary part I added to my question to make sure I understood it correctly?